# install Mendeley desktop

Tags: software-installation, mendeley

I had Mendeley desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 and previous versions. It runned perfectly. Now I have the 20.04.1 Ubuntu version and I'm not able to install it. After downloading it from the Mendeley page and trying to install it appears a message: There is a missing file.

Thankyou for your help.

Comment: Need more details. Which exactly file have you downloaded, from which link/URL?

Comment: OK... tell us the name of the missing file. Need more info.

Comment: See https://www.mendeley.com/contact-support/

Comment: I've downloaded mendeleydesktop-1.19.4-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 (this is zip file) from https://www.mendeley.com/download-desktop-new/#download. after extracting and go to install, it appears that there is a missing file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install some dependendent packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 \
gconf2-common libgconf-2-4 libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7-minimal \
libpython2.7-stdlib python-is-python2 python2 python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal
```

But to keep problem reproducible I would recommend to install deb-packaged version instead:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt/pool/main/m/mendeleydesktop/mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb
```

as it does this for you and will install desktop-shortcut with icon.

Comment: After installing the deb-pacaged version it worked.